# Can we retain __proto__ when we transfer object over an iframe

Tags: javascript

I am transferring an object from parent window to an iframe using window.postMessage. However the when we receive the object on the iframe, the object loses **proto**. Is there a way to get a workaround for this

Comment: Send the class's code as well, then use it to set the prototype? Even better if the iframe can have the class already in its code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window.postMessage` uses **Structured Clone Algorithm** to pass objects between bounds by cloning recursively. It comes with limitations as well as stated in [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)

#### As per the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) Certain object properties are not preserved:

> - The lastIndex property of RegExp objects is not preserved.
> - Property descriptors, setters, getters, and similar metadata-like features are not 
>     duplicated. For example, if an object is marked readonly with a property descriptor, it will be read/write in the duplicate, since that's the default.
> - **The prototype chain is not walked or duplicated.**

#### Workaround:

Send the **prototype chain** as an object along with **data / payload** and use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) or [`Object.setprototypeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) method on the receiver end to correct the prototype of the received object.